Align views inside of the ScrollView to the bottom in SwiftUI
I have a scrollView with a big "progress" line on the left and a text with a button on the right, maybe I am missing something, but Spacers are not working correctly and this button and text are not at the very bottom of the screen. (I used a dark rectangle to see the frame at the bottom)
So I need to move this rectangle to the bottom of the line.
Simplified code:
GeometryReader { geo in
        ZStack {
            // Gradient Background
            AnimatedGradBackground(type: .blackWhite)
            
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                        // MARK: Main Line
                        (ZStack with some code)

                      
                        Spacer()
                        
                        // MARK: Text and Goal Button
                        VStack {
                            // Goal Button
                            if showMainButton {
                                Circle()
                                    .opacity(0)
                                    .overlay {
                                        GoalButtonView(completedLongPress: $completedLongPress)
                                    }
                                    .scaleEffect(0.9)
                                    .transition(
                                        .asymmetric(
                                            insertion: .move(edge: .top).combined(with: .opacity),
                                            removal: .scale
                                        ))
                            }
                            // Text
                            if showTransitionText {
                                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                                    Text("The Hardest Part")
                                        .font(.title3.bold())
                                    
                                    Text("This is actually the most important step you can take")
                                }
                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                .frame(width: geo.size.width / 1.8)
                                .transition(
                                    .asymmetric(
                                        insertion: .move(edge: .top).combined(with: .opacity),
                                        removal: .move(edge: .bottom).combined(with: .opacity)
                                    ))
                            }
                            
                            Rectangle() // rect to see the frame
                        }
                        .animation(.easeInOut.speed(0.3), value: isLinePressed)
                    }
                }
                .frame(minHeight: geo.size.height * Double(checkPointsNum / 2)) // I tried default frame and this frame still the same result
            }
            .defaultScrollAnchor(.bottom)
        }
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea()



Can you please provide a minimal example of what you tried?

oh yes, so sorry, I will edit the post

It seems like the Spacer should go inside the VStack.

If I put Spacer inside a Vstack or LazyVstack it doesn't change anything

Is geo.height the hight of the screen or the height of the ZStack? Did you try to set the alignment of some of the ZStacks? My guess would be the most outer ZStack.

Yeah, I tried that. Just fixed it with a ZStack(.bottom) inside clear rectangle stretched  behind the button and text
